# Azure Websockets connection stuck between connecting and disconnecting

Tags: node.js, azure, websocket, azure-web-app-service

I'm working on a project which uses WebSockets, I've deployed it to heroku and everything works fine but when I deploy the same project on Azure with WebSockets turned on the socket keeps connecting and disconnecting with a gap of split second. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect you haven't enabled WebSockets in the application settings of your Web App. Go to the [portal](http://portal.azure.com) and find the your Web app. On the Web App blade, click on "Settings" from the top and then "Application Settings" on the blade that will open. There is an option called "Web Sockets". Turn it "On" and "Save".

I would also restart the Web app, just to be on the safe side, although it's not required.

Try again and it should work.

Comment: Hey thanks, as I've already ,mentioned in the question I Have turned WebSockets on, that's why it **connects and disconnects**

Comment: Hm.. I could swear it wasn't there when I answered.. anyhow. Did you follow a specific guide to do the deployment of node to Azure? If yes, which one? I just need to see what it covers before I start speculating what might be wrong. Thx.

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/web-sites-nodejs-develop-deploy-mac/ this is what I followed, I'm on Elementary OS Luna based on Ubuntu

Comment: hey if you have any comments or possible solutions please post here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is an article in the Azure Documentation which discusses Web Sockets in some detail, this article also includes a [Troubleshooting](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-nodejs-chat-app-socketio/#_troubleshooting) section which may help answer your question. I believe the most common resolution for this issue is that IIS is still attempting to handle the Web Socket connections if that is the case the following settings need to be configured in the Web.config:

```
<webSocket enabled="false"/>
```